# Can I Enable Self-Registration Redirection in Conjunction with SSO?

Tags: single-sign-on, redirect, cross-domain, self-registration, registration

I have a question about Salesforce registration redirection capabilities and I am getting unclear answers from my googlings. Here is the situation: When an *anonymous* user at our partner site partner.example.com (uses a subdomain of our main domain) clicks a particular link that requires the user be logged in, they are redirected to the connect app (SAML) SSO login page. If that user does not have an account with us, they click the “not a member” link and initiate the registration process. At the end of that they are redirected to our default registration landing page on communitysite.example.com. First they have to figure out how to get back to the partner site page they got redirected from on their own. When they get there they are still not logged in, because they have not yet logged in via the SSO login. This is a very frustrating situation for our users.

1. Is it possible to do redirection after registration? The doc at https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9062I000000QwcCQAS seems to suggest it is but I cannot tell if that would enable redirection to an external site.
2. If registration redirection is possible, is our "not a member" link supposed to be getting the redirection URL given to the login page implanted in its vars?
3. If that is not happening, what would be the best way to fix that? (Javascript? Custom lightning login page or component?)
4. Even if we can get the person redirected after registration, they are still not going to be logged in at the partner site, right? Is there a way we can “force” an SSO connection without the user actually logging in through the connected app login? (I have been wanting to know about this possibility for a while, because needing to login again in a same-looking screen has generated a number of complaints; I think I could solve this with cross-subdomain cookies but I can find no way to write one in SF that would include the session ID.)

How does everyone else handle this? We can't be the only ones with this problem.

Note: If the user already has an account with us and logs in correctly at the SSO login, they are properly redirected back to where they came from.

Comment: Hello, I assume you mean the self-registration is happening outside of Salesforce, do I get it right?

Comment: The self-registration is happening inside Salesforce.

Comment: I have just successfully implemented this using OpenID Connect, but I don't know anything about SAML. The 'Not a member' link on the login form should automatically preserve the redirect URI. The approach in the forum post is useful if you want to link users *directly* to the registration page and have them redirected back to your connected app afterwards. Note that you can only redirect to the redirect URI that is registered for the particular connected app in Salesforce – you can't just redirect to some arbitrary URI after login/registration.